# Codeigniter - Foreach for all the "Faq" in the language file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have over 7 languages on my website. I have a FAQ page where all the faq's are displayed in English. I had the FAQ's translated in all 7 languages and were stored in their language folders.

So my folder structure is:

```
languages
  english
     faq_lang.php
 french
     faq_lang.php
 spanish
     faq_lang.php
 finnish
     faq_lang.php
 swedish
     faq_lang.php
```

As you can see, I have got the same far_lang.php folder on all languages containing the FAQ in that language.

Now on my faq file, I had an `foreach` loop to loop through all questions and answers from database. Now that they are all in the faq_lang file, I don't know how I can do that.

They are all like this:

```
$lang['faq_1'] = "How do I use this";
$lang['faq_1_ans'] = "Just visit google and search";
//and so on
```

I don't know how I can do that. I tried doing this but it did not work.

```
foreach ($this->lang->lang('faq') as $faq) {
//stuff 
}
```

How can I do this?

thanks guys!

Comment: do you want to show that multiple language FAQ in one page at once ?

Comment: No, show whatever language the user has selected

Comment: so, you expected to show one language based on a user selected ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use your language in codeigniter, you can use combobox to provide your multiple language. And load your file, ex :

```
$this->load->helper('language');
//$this->lang->load(filename,language);
$this->lang->load('faq','english');
// You can use combobox to automatically change the load function for that lang
//$this->lang->load('faq','french');
```

and test it :

```
echo lang('faq_1');
echo lang('faq_1_ans');
```

to dynamically change the `$this->lang->load('faq',your_lang_dir);`, put that load in your controller like this below :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $lang = (!empty($_GET['cb_lang'])?$_GET['cb_lang']:'indonesia');
        $this->load->helper('language');
        $this->lang->load('faq',$lang);
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

and your view like this :

```
<div id="body">
    <?php
        echo "<form method='GET' action='".site_url('welcome/index')."'>
        <label for='Manufacturer'>Select Language : </label>
        <select id='cb_lang' name='cb_lang'>
            <option value='indonesia'>Indonesia</option>
            <option value='english'>English</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' name='lang' value='Select'/>
        </form><br />";
        echo lang('faq_1')."<br />";
        echo lang('faq_1_ans');
    ?>
</div>
```

Hope this help you a little... :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```php
// Controller
$this->lang->load('faq', 'english');

// View
foreach ($this->lang->language as $key => $faq) {
    echo 'Showing the key <b>' . $key . '</b> with value <b>' . $faq . '</b><br/>';
}
```

The output will be something like:

Showing the key **faq_1** with value **How do I use this**
Showing the key **faq_1_ans** with value **Just visit google and search**